# Jenkinsfile Pipeline: reach ip of sidecar of host

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running Jenkins on GKE with the Kubernetes plugin. I added a postgres container as a sidecar with the jnlp agent container. It's reachable on `localhost:5432` from the agent. I also mount the GKE node's Docker socket and bin in the agent so I can spin up "sister" containers. This is also working fine.

Now I want to do the following:

```
pipeline {

    stages {

        stage('pytest') {

            agent {
                docker {
                    image "<image created in a previous stage>"
                    args '--add-host=database:\$(hostname\\ -i)'
                }
            }

            steps {
                // use postgres in sidecar of jnlp agent
                // e.g. on `database:5432`
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Doing this manually works great, but in Jenkins the above fails with:

```
Error: invalid argument "database:$(hostname -i)" for --add-host=database:$(hostname -i): invalid IP address in add-host: "$(hostname -i)"
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to escape the above? Or perhaps a completely different way of approaching this problem?

I don't have Docker 18.03+ available on GKE (stuck at `17.03.2-ce`) so I can't do `host.docker.internal`

`docker run --network host` does nothing either.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a sidecar you don't need `$(hostname)` you should be able to connect with `localhost:5432`. Containers in pods share the same address space.

Another option is to use [`initContainers`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) in your pod spec to set up the file that you want. You can write a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <<EOF
pipeline {

    stages {

        stage('pytest') {

            agent {
                docker {
                    image "<image created in a previous stage>"
                    args "--add-host=database:${HOSTMAME}"
                }
            }

            steps {
                // use postgres in sidecar of jnlp agent
                // e.g. on `database:5432`
            }
        }
    }
}
EOF > /your-config-file
```

`${HOSTNAME}` being the environment variable in the pod.

Comment: Thanks, but the `agent { docker` part creates a sister pod next to the agent+postgres_sidecar pod, therefore the sidecar is not reachable on `localhost`.

Comment: And what do you mean by "set up the file that you want"?

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches to this,

1. give the docker agent container a name (say `test-runner`), create a custom bridged network (say `test-network`), manually attach `test-runner` to `test-network`, then create the sidecar with `--network test-network`;
2. add an argument `--add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway` to the docker agent container, map the sidecar's service port (`5432`) to host, then access the service port via `host.docker.internal:5432`.